# How can I grant server-side access to my Firebase DB with rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a Firebase DB yet. It's still in the sandbox stage and I don't have any rules *yet*.

I have a collaborator who is maintaining a server that generates data. I would like that server to be able to push data to my Firebase database.

Is there any way (perhaps by generating a new secret key, or a service account for that DB) that I can grant that server Write permissions to only certain fields in my DB?

Comment: How is that server accessing the database? Because if it uses the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start), it automatically has administrative access to everything.

Comment: Right, exactly. I'd like to avoid that, if it's possible. The server doesn't currently have access to anything. I'd like to *grant* access, but preferably only to specific paths.

Comment: In that case you'll want to [authenticate the Admin SDK with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges). If you're using a regular SDK, you're authenticated as a regular user; so the security rules for regular users would apply.